# How to resize and Compress files(pdf,xls,doc,pptx,.....etc) base64 before uploading to the server in android

Tags: java, android

Please find my code below:

```
InputStream in = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri);
       byte[]     bytes = getBytes(Objects.requireNonNull(in));
          String  base64string = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

How to resize and Compress files(pdf,xls,doc,pptx,.....etc) base64 before uploading to the server in android